# how to check if there is one selected radio button among the group?

Tags: php

Good day... I am here again to ask your idea on solving this problem. I have displayed questions using while loop. Each questions have 5 radio buttons each. The problem is, I have to check if one among the group of radio button is clicked. How to do this one using php or javascript? I have here my sample program.. Thanks in advance...

```
$ctr = 1;
$partIDTemp = "";
while($rowItems = mysql_fetch_array($resultItems)){                          
   if( $partIDTemp != $rowItems['partID'] ){
      if($ctr != 1)
         echo "<tr ></tr>";
         echo "<tr style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold'><td colspan='3'>" . $rowItems['description'] . "</td></tr>";
   }
echo "<tr bgcolor=white style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'><td align='center'>" . $ctr . "</td>";
$rows =$rowItems['WPID'];
echo "<td>" . $rowItems['descriptions']. "</td>";
$response = "response_".$rows;
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='$response' value='5' />
      <input type='radio' name='$response' value='4' />
      <input type='radio' name='$response' value='3' />
      <input type='radio' name='$response' value='2' />
      <input type='radio' name='$response' value='1' />
  </td>";
$ctr++;
$partIDTemp = $rowItems['partID'];
}
```

Comment: Your code generates the html for the radio button. Are you looking to set a checked one then or are you trying to figure out how to find the selected one after a post?

Comment: after submitting the form containing the radio button, it must be checked if one of the radio button is clicked. if at least one group  is not selected among the items, the form must not be submitted

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javascript (No JQuery)

```
function isRadioSelected() {
    var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {
        if (radiobuttons[i].type === 'radio' && radiobuttons[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can then use this function to validate your form

Comment: so, this code snippet will get the value of the radio buttons clicked?

Comment: Yup it should do that. Is that what you want?

Comment: This will not only get the radio button, but every input element on the entire document

Comment: It will however only process the radiobuttons from the document

Comment: Not so..  I can now get the values of the radio button clicked. What I want is that, if the form will be submitted, there will be checking if all in every item, there is a corresponding radio button value. If at least one of the item do not have a corresponding radio button value, the form must not be submitted.

Comment: I edited it to change it into a function to check if its selected and return true if it is and false if it isnt. You can add this in your form validation

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkRadio() {
  return ($('input[name="the_name"]:checked').size() > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are monitoring the users activity, you have you use Javascript, unless you can wait till the form is submitted.

Using jQuery, you can attach a snippet on the submit event like this

```
$("#formid").submit(function() {
   var checked = $(this).children('input[name="checkboxname"]:checked').val();

});
```

Pure javascript of this would be this

```
var myform = document.forms['myform'];
myform.onsubmit = function() {
   var elements = myform.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var value;
   for(var i =0; i< elements.length; i++) {
      if(elements[i].type == "radio" && elements[i].checked) {
         value = elements[i].value;
         break;
      }
   }
   alert(value);
   return false;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/PDZGP/)

Comment: I am really sorry, but, can this be done using javascript? I really don't know about jQuery.. hope you'll consider..

Comment: @assehj, I have update my answer with the javascript solution